# Forcing Rails's app.get to redo the request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using the following code to perform a request on the server from within a rake task:

```
app = ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.new(Rails.application)
app.host!('localhost:3000')
app.get(path)
```

This works well.

However, if I call `app.get(path)` again with the same path, the request is not repeated and the previous result is returned.

Is there a way I can force app.get to repeat the call?

Comment: How do you know that the second `app.get(path)` doesn't repeat the request? I just looked through the code for `ActionDispatch::Integration::Session`, and there's no indication of any caching there.

Comment: @henrikhodne any `puts` present in the controller method that services the route will only output on the first request.

Comment: @henrikhodne you are right. It's not `ActionDispatch::Integration::Session` doing any caching, but the standard rails caching pipeline doing it's thing, as with a standard HTTP request. I've elaborated in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked out what's going on.

Basically the observation "the request is not repeated" is Rails' own caching in action. Which makes sense, `app.get` is treated as any other request, if caching is enabled, the cache is returned, and if it's not, it will repeat (as @henrikhodne claimed).  This explains why a `puts` in the cached controller will not output the second time.

To verify, add a `puts` in 2 controller methods, but only set the `expires_in` in the second. The first one will repeat the output, the second will not.

The way to force the request to repeat is to bust the cache by modifying the URL e.g.
`app.get("/")` becomes `app.get("/?r=123456")` as you would if using HTTP.  It all seems obvious in hindsight, basically `app.get` is treated exactly as a client request, and all the same rules apply.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reset the session:

```
app.reset!
```

---

Here is how it works when reset,

```
def reset!
    @https = false
    @controller = @request = @response = nil
    @_mock_session = nil
    @request_count = 0
    @url_options = nil

    self.host        = DEFAULT_HOST
    self.remote_addr = "127.0.0.1"
    self.accept      = "text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml," +
                       "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png," +
                       "*/*;q=0.5"

    unless defined? @named_routes_configured
      # the helpers are made protected by default--we make them public for
      # easier access during testing and troubleshooting.
      @named_routes_configured = true
    end
  end
```

Otherwise it will just re-use the last response:

```
# this is a private method in Session, it will called every time you call `get/post, etc`
def process
  ......
  @request_count += 1
  @request  = ActionDispatch::Request.new(session.last_request.env)
  response = _mock_session.last_response
  @response = ActionDispatch::TestResponse.new(response.status, response.headers, response.body)
  @html_document = nil
  ....
end
```

Good luck!

Comment: It actually doesn't reuse the last response. If you look a little further up in the code, it send the request to the `_mock_session` overriding the `last_response` attribute. `#reset!` may still work, though.

Comment: `app.reset!` did not make a difference in my testing. My issue was rail's own caching system being activated (as it is for a normal HTTP request), see my answer. I appreciate your help investigating this though!